# ECCUBEの商品データ(商品名・画像・リンク)を静的サイトへ表示する方法と一般的な工数を知りたいです

Tags: api, ec-cube

### 知りたいこと

ECCUBEの商品データ(商品名・画像・リンク)を静的サイトへ表示する方法と一般的な工数を知りたいです。

### 質問の背景

ECCUBEに登録されている商品のデータを静的サイトに反映したいのですが、ECCUBEやAPIなどの知見が皆無のため、一般的な連携の方法やそれに対する工数を知りたく、質問させていただきました。

### 調べたこと

下記2つの方法で可能との情報は得ておりますが、知見が皆無のため確信が欲しいです。
方法①：REST APIを使用して商品情報を取得し、別サーバーのサイトに出力する方法
方法②：ECCUBEのデータベースから商品情報をエクスポートする方法

### 質問

上記2つの方法は可能、または一般的な方法でしょうか？
その際、それぞれの対応にどれくらい時間を要するものでしょうか？

上記ご確認とご回答のほどよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 「工数がどれくらい」は EC-CUBE の話題に限らず、アンケートに近い質問になるので、[当サイトで避けるべき質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) の様に思います。 / 使い方に関してはまず [マニュアル](https://www.ec-cube.net/manual/ec-cube4/) をまず熟読したり、[専用のサポートサイト](https://www.ec-cube.net/support/) もあるようなのでそちらを優先して頼った方が解決が早いかもしれません。

Answer (score 0):

まず、EC-CUBEのデータを静的サイトへ出力こと自体が一般的ではないことをご承知ください。

①ですが、現在の最新バージョンである EC-CUBE4系に REST API はありません。
EC-CUBE4系に標準添付されている API プラグインは、 GraphQL を使用しています。
EC-CUBE4系で REST API を使用したい場合は、自力で一から作成する必要があります。
EC-CUBE2系、3系には REST API がありますが、開発途上であり、それぞれ簡易的なものですので、必要な要件を満たしていない可能性があります。

上記のような理由から、②の方が少ない工数で実現できそうです。
しかし、商品情報は、運用中のショップによって複雑度が大きく異なります。
商品名・画像・リンクのみでしたら、 dtb_product 及び dtb_product_image テーブル(EC-CUBE4系の場合)の情報のみを出力してやれば良いので、基本的なPHPや、SQLを扱うスキルがあれば1日もかからないと思われます。
商品価格やカテゴリ情報も出力する必要がある場合は、あと5つほどのテーブルを参照する必要がでてきます。
上記のような情報で、おおよその作業イメージのつく方なら、1週間もかからないでしょう。
全くイメージのつかない方や、これから PHP やデータベースのことを勉強します！という方だと1ヶ月くらいかかるかもしれません。